# How can I calculate the correlation of my residuals ? Spark-Scala

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, forecasting

I need to know if my residuals are correlated or not. I didn't find a way to do it using Spark-Scala on Databricks. 
And i conclude that i should export my project to R to use [acf function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/acf.html).

Does someone know a trick to do it using Spark-Scala on Databricks ?

For those who need more information : I'm currently working on Sales Forecasting. I used a Regression Forest using different features. Then, I need to evaluate the quality of my forecast. To check this, i read on this [paper](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/6) that residuals were a good way to see if your forecasting model is good or bad. In any cases, you can still improve it but it's just to make my opinion on my forecast model and compared it to others models.

Currently, I have one dataframe like the one below. It's a part of the testing data/out-of-sample data. (*I casted prediction and residuals to IntegerType, that's why at the 3rd row 40 - 17 = 22*)
[image]

Comment: you want correlation of residuals with what other column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `Spark 2.1.1`.

You can find correlation between columns using [spark ml library function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-statistics.html#correlations)

Lets first import the classes.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.corr
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics
```

Now prepare the input DataFrame :

```
scala> val seqRow = Seq(
     |     ("2017-04-27",13,21),
     |     ("2017-04-26",7,16),
     |     ("2017-04-25",40,17),
     |     ("2017-04-24",17,17),
     |     ("2017-04-21",10,20),
     |     ("2017-04-20",9,19),
     |     ("2017-04-19",30,30),
     |     ("2017-04-18",18,25),
     |     ("2017-04-14",32,28),
     |     ("2017-04-13",39,18),
     |     ("2017-04-12",2,4),
     |     ("2017-04-11",8,24),
     |     ("2017-04-10",18,27),
     |     ("2017-04-07",6,17),
     |     ("2017-04-06",13,29),
     |     ("2017-04-05",10,17),
     |     ("2017-04-04",6,8),
     |     ("2017-04-03",20,32)
     | )
seqRow: Seq[(String, Int, Int)] = List((2017-04-27,13,21), (2017-04-26,7,16), (2017-04-25,40,17), (2017-04-24,17,17), (2017-04-21,10,20), (2017-04-20,9,19), (2017-04-19,30,30), (2017-04-18,18,25), (2017-04-14,32,28), (2017-04-13,39,18), (2017-04-12,2,4), (2017-04-11,8,24), (2017-04-10,18,27), (2017-04-07,6,17), (2017-04-06,13,29), (2017-04-05,10,17), (2017-04-04,6,8), (2017-04-03,20,32))

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(seqRow)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[51] at parallelize at <console>:34

scala> val input_df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF("date","amount","prediction").withColumn("residuals",'amount - 'prediction)
input_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [date: string, amount: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> input_df.show(false)
+----------+------+----------+---------+
|date      |amount|prediction|residuals|
+----------+------+----------+---------+
|2017-04-27|13    |21        |-8       |
|2017-04-26|7     |16        |-9       |
|2017-04-25|40    |17        |23       |
|2017-04-24|17    |17        |0        |
|2017-04-21|10    |20        |-10      |
|2017-04-20|9     |19        |-10      |
|2017-04-19|30    |30        |0        |
|2017-04-18|18    |25        |-7       |
|2017-04-14|32    |28        |4        |
|2017-04-13|39    |18        |21       |
|2017-04-12|2     |4         |-2       |
|2017-04-11|8     |24        |-16      |
|2017-04-10|18    |27        |-9       |
|2017-04-07|6     |17        |-11      |
|2017-04-06|13    |29        |-16      |
|2017-04-05|10    |17        |-7       |
|2017-04-04|6     |8         |-2       |
|2017-04-03|20    |32        |-12      |
+----------+------+----------+---------+
```

The values of `residuals` for row `2017-04-14` and `2017-04-13` don't match as i am subtracting `amount - prediction` for `residuals`

Now proceeding forward to calculate correlation between  all the columns.
*This method is used for calculating correlation if number of columns are more and you need correlation between each column to others.*

**First** we drop the column whose correlation is not to be calculated

```
scala> val drop_date_df = input_df.drop('date)
drop_date_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [amount: int, prediction: int ... 1 more field]

scala> drop_date_df.show
+------+----------+---------+
|amount|prediction|residuals|
+------+----------+---------+
|    13|        21|       -8|
|     7|        16|       -9|
|    40|        17|       23|
|    17|        17|        0|
|    10|        20|      -10|
|     9|        19|      -10|
|    30|        30|        0|
|    18|        25|       -7|
|    32|        28|        4|
|    39|        18|       21|
|     2|         4|       -2|
|     8|        24|      -16|
|    18|        27|       -9|
|     6|        17|      -11|
|    13|        29|      -16|
|    10|        17|       -7|
|     6|         8|       -2|
|    20|        32|      -12|
+------+----------+---------+
```

Since there are more than 2 column for correlation, we need to find correlation matrix.
For calculating **correlation matrix** we need **RDD[Vector]** as you can see in spark example for correlation.

```
scala> val dense_rdd = drop_date_df.rdd.map{row =>
     |         val first = row.getAs[Integer]("amount")
     |         val second = row.getAs[Integer]("prediction")
     |         val third = row.getAs[Integer]("residuals")
     |         Vectors.dense(first.toDouble,second.toDouble,third.toDouble)}
dense_rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = MapPartitionsRDD[62] at map at <console>:40

scala> val correlMatrix: Matrix = Statistics.corr(dense_rdd, "pearson")
correlMatrix: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix =
1.0                  0.40467032516705076  0.782939330961529
0.40467032516705076  1.0                  -0.2520531290688281
0.782939330961529    -0.2520531290688281  1.0
```

The order of column remains same but you loose out the column names.
You can find good resources about structure of correlation matrix.

Since you want to find the correlation of residuals with other two columns.
We can explore other options

**Hive** [corr UDAF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF))

```
scala> drop_date_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table")

scala> val corr_query_df = spark.sql("select corr(amount,residuals) as amount_residuals_corr,corr(prediction,residuals) as prediction_residual_corr from temp_table")
corr_query_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [amount_residuals_corr: double, prediction_residual_corr: double]

scala> corr_query_df.show
+---------------------+------------------------+
|amount_residuals_corr|prediction_residual_corr|
+---------------------+------------------------+
|   0.7829393309615287|      -0.252053129068828|
+---------------------+------------------------+
```

**Spark *corr* function** [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)

```
scala> val corr_df = drop_date_df.select(
     |                 corr('amount,'residuals).as("amount_residuals_corr"),
     |                 corr('prediction,'residuals).as("prediction_residual_corr"))
corr_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [amount_residuals_corr: double, prediction_residual_corr: double]

scala> corr_df.show
+---------------------+------------------------+
|amount_residuals_corr|prediction_residual_corr|
+---------------------+------------------------+
|   0.7829393309615287|      -0.252053129068828|
+---------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete example with explanations ! 
I have just one more question ; 
**The residuals are uncorrelated. If there are correlations between residuals, then there is information left in the residuals which should be used in computing forecasts.** quote from the article of the paper linked in the main question. 
Does it mean that i need to calculate the autocorrelation of residuals ? 
If it's the case, do u have any idea of how to do it ?